# Can i concatenate my String containing data with a mysql Query?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code portion as :

```
String t = (tname2.getText());
     String h = (value2.getText());

     PreparedStatement ps ;

     if(h.length()>2)
     {
         ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM "+t+" where empname = "+ h);
         //ps.setString(2,h);
         ps.executeUpdate();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record deleted !", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     }
```

Now, the line `ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM "+t+" where empname = "+ h);` isn't working . It works the other way around using "?". As like `"Delete * from "+ t +" where empname =?";`
and then setting the value of empname. I wanna know , if there's a way i can do things using concatenation of my empname with the query?? Can someone provide a few hints please?? `

Comment: What is the reason to use a _prepared statement_ and then concatenating the query string yourself?

Comment: Actually i used the prepared statement the way it is used, but then it kept causing me an error which i couldn't track. So i moved to the other way.

Comment: In SQL, Strings need to be inside `'` otherwise it will think you have a field name or keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PreparedStatement with a parametrized query and set the value. 
This using will also prevent SQL injection. 
Because concatenate values into your query make vulnerable to SQL injection.

eg.

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM "+t+" where empname = ?");
psmt.setString(1, h);
```

Comment: You can't use a parameter for the object (table) name, only for values. So you need to remove the first parameter and replace it with concatenation (and preferably a whitelist check of the name).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel. Thank for your comment.Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing properly opening and closing double quotes:

Try this:

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM " + t + " where empname = '" + h + "'");
```

Comment: wow! It worked. Thanks. Could you explain the working please ?

Comment: because query should have between " start and " end.

Comment: You search a string in the db, so you have to enclose your string with ' or ". 
If you search a number you don't have to do that.

I think the answer of Ye Win is better, because it avoid SQL Injections.